# Q: Vue progress

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm new to js and vue in general and just playing around till i get some more knowledge.
I am trying to play around with a progress bar and i got kinda stuck. When my progress bar hit 0 the data goes away and i got that to work, but i also want it to come back as soon it gain more progress (without refreshing) and it just doesn't let me get the data back, my guess is that i would need some kind of function to get it back here is my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app" v-show="show">
    <vue-ellipse-progress :progress="progress" colorFill="#955251" :noData="nodata" :size="size" :thickness="10" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'app',
  props: {
    nodata: Boolean,
  },

  components: {},

  data() {
    return {
      size: 100,
      show: true,
      progress: 50,


    };
  },
  mounted() {
    if(this.progress === 0) this.nodata = true
  },
  methods: {},
};
</script>
```

I tried stuff like : `"if(this.progress === Number) this.nodata = false"`
I did get it to work with : `"if(this.progress === 1) this.nodata = false"` but the issue is that the progress bar have to go through "1" so if it instantly goes to lets say "20" it will still have no data.
I could do it with all 100% like

```
"if(this.progress === 1) this.nodata = false"
"if(this.progress === 2) this.nodata = false"
"if(this.progress === 3) this.nodata = false"
```

but i'm like there must be a easier way.

Hope someone could help me out :)

Answer (score 1):

With Vue 2 and the Vue CLI, I built some sample Single File Components based mostly on your code.  Since you are new to Vue, a couple of points:

- Props are used to pass data from a parent component to a child
  component, and you don't show a parent component to pass your
  `nodata` prop.
- My example uses a parent and a child component, but I am
  passing `progressProp` instead of `noData`, which I converted
  to a computed property.
- Your existing code is mutating your `nodata` prop, which is not recommended.  So instead create a local data option and initialize it with the prop.  Then you can mutate the local data option.  I did this by initializing my `progress` data option and my `progressProp`.

Here are the components:

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <vue-ellipse-progress :progressProp="50" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import VueEllipseProgress from './VueEllipseProgress'

  export default {
    components: {
      VueEllipseProgress
    }
  }
</script>
```

VueEllipseProgress.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="vue-ellipse-progress">
    <vue-ellipse-progress :progress="progress" colorFill="#955251" :noData="noData" :size="size" :thickness="10" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="select-progress">Select Progress Amount</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="select-progress" v-model="progress">
        <option :value="0">0</option>
        <option :value="25">25</option>
        <option :value="50">50</option>
        <option :value="75">75</option>
        <option :value="100">100</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'VueEllipseProgress',
    props: {
      progressProp: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
      noData() {
        return (this.progress === 0) ? true : false;
      }
    },
    data() {
      return {
        size: 100,
        show: true,
        progress: this.progressProp,
      };
    },
    methods: {},
  };
</script>
```

Comment: nitpick: This `return this.progress === 0` already returns boolean so no need for ternary operator